# Is there a way to find out the estimate of Linux kernel version usage in the world?

Tags: linux-kernel, version, statistics

Currently I am writing my bachelor thesis and as a part of it I need some statistics about the Linux kernel. 
Is there any website or publication that would provide some estimates on which kernel versions are used the most nowadays?
Preferably I need the statistics of all devices (PCs, phones, servers, IoT devices etc.), but it doesn't really matter whether they're counted separately or all together.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I am grateful even for estimates of usage of different distros and their versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no central authority distributing the Linux kernel, and many, many Linux devices don’t have any way of communicating with the outside world, so there’s no way to get detailed statistics on the usage of various kernel versions.

There are a number of data sources which can be used to get a (very) vague idea of the popularity of different kernels:

- the already mentioned [LinuxCounter](https://www.linuxcounter.net/) project, which also [details its own limitations](https://www.linuxcounter.net/statistics);
- various distribution “popularity contests”, such as [Debian’s](http://popcon.debian.org/main/by_inst) (look for `linux-image-` with a version number) or [Ubuntu’s](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/) (which no longer distinguishes kernel versions) — note that these are self-selecting;
- the [Steam hardware survey](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey?platform=linux), which lists the major distribution versions (these map to single kernel versions, at least for Ubuntu and Linux Mint);
- [Google Play Store statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)#Platform_usage), which give a theoretical base-line for kernel versions (see [Wikipedia’s Android version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)) although the actual kernel version in use depends largely on the hardware rather than the version of Android in use.

You could also try to find out which versions of the kernel are shipped with SoCs, and try to determine the SoCs’ popularity (for example, 2.6.32 and 3.10 are very common in this kind of market).

This is still very fragmentary. The majority of “computer-style devices” running Linux run Android, which limits the scope (in theory, only LTS kernels, and I think Google have specific kernel usage statistics which they publish from time to time, although I can’t find them right now). But that pales in comparison to all the embedded devices running Linux — your TV, your Blu-ray player, perhaps even your car, your microwave oven, your fridge, …

Answer (score 0):

There's the [LinuxCounter](https://www.linuxcounter.net) project, which also features a page with [kernel statistics](https://www.linuxcounter.net/statistics/kernels). However, the representativity of this numbers is disputable, but that's the problem with most probably any survey in the Open Source community. The problems and drawbacks with this figures, and obtaining them, is mentioned in the [statistics main page](https://www.linuxcounter.net/statistics).

Comment: Yeah I found that as well. But if I understand it correctly, the numbers are not estimate of all the versions in use, but statistics calculated from registrations by the LinuxCounter users...

Comment: Yes, and I think that's as close as you can get, as there are no official sales statistics you can base other estimations upon. Being Open Source, and free to use (and drop) on as many devices as you please, how should one be able to collect reliable figures? See the statistics main page on more in-depth information: https://www.linuxcounter.net/statistics

Comment: That will have to do for me, I just wondered if there are any other statistics. Thank you very much.